# Arduino compile error on only certain programs

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

I've been having a problem with my arduino compilor. What happens is if I run certain programs It results in a compiler error. On other programs every thing compiles normally. But If certain I run certain programs I get the error

> "exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega
>   2560."

Here's the code I am trying to run:

---

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

int px =0;
int py = 0;
int X;
int Y;
String serialData;
  AF_DCMotor right(3);
  AF_DCMotor left(4);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  right.setSpeed(400);
  left.setSpeed(400);
}


void serialEvent() {
serialData = Serial.readString();
  X = Xc(serialData);
  Y = Yc(serialData);
  if(X < px){
    right.run(BACKWARD);
    left.run(BACKWARD);
    delay(X * 10);
    px = X;
  }
  right.run(RELEASE);
  left.run(RELEASE);
}

int Xc(String data){
  data.remove(data.indexOf("Y"));
  data.remove(data.indexOf("X"), 1);
  return data.toInt();
}

int Yc(String data){
  data.remove(0,data.indexOf("Y") + 1);
  return data.toInt();
}
```

---

I've tried to compile for other boards but I still get the same error.

Comment: * if I run certain programs It results in a compiler error.* If you're getting a compiler error, the program doesn't compile and can't be run. If the program runs, you're not getting a compiler error. If you're getting the same error on *other boards*, that means your code isn't compiling at all. You should be getting more information than what you've provided. Please post the entire content lf all error messages you get.

Comment: From here I can see two major problems with your code. First, it is missing `loop` function, second, the declaration of `Xc` and `Yc` functions must be set before `serialEvent`.

Comment: `<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x264): undefined reference to 'loop'` - I think it's pretty much self explaining. And there are also some warnings like passing 400 to uint8_t (too big) and some tautologies in adafruit library

Comment: "exit status 1 Error compiling... " is never the only error, just a final summary. Look more carefully.